# Why does pipenv add extension to the end of the name?

Tags: pipenv

I have a project that is called "sportanalitica". When I run `pipenv shell` it enters the virtual environment and I see "(sportanalitica-KnWqfC-u)". Also if I install anything it says

> Pipfile.lock (295b1e) out of date, updating to (74c969)…

Is there any solution or anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing is wrong. That's just how `pipenv` works.

> I run `pipenv shell` it enters the virtual environment and I see - (sportanalitica-KnWqfC-u)

That's just how pipenv names the virtual environment when it is created: `<folder-name>-<hash>`. That will also be an actual folder on your machine. See pipenv docs [Virtualenv mapping caveat](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#virtualenv-mapping-caveat):

> - Pipenv automatically maps projects to their specific virtualenvs.
> - The virtualenv is stored globally with the name of the project’s root directory plus the hash of the full path to the project’s root (e.g., `my_project-a3de50`).

```
~$ mkdir sportanalitica
~$ cd sportanalitica/
sportanalitica$ pipenv shell
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/me/sportanalitica/Pipfile
...
✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /Users/me/.venvs/sportanalitica-3tdk8qV0
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
...

(sportanalitica) sportanalitica$ pipenv --venv
/Users/me/.venvs/sportanalitica-3tdk8qV0

(sportanalitica) sportanalitica$ ll /Users/me/.venvs/sportanalitica-3tdk8qV0
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  23 cerberus  staff   736B Dec 30 13:07 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 cerberus  staff    96B Dec 30 13:07 lib/
-rw-r--r--   1 cerberus  staff   470B Dec 30 13:07 pyvenv.cfg
```

That's how pipenv knows that every time you run `pipenv shell` inside that same sportanalitica folder, it will find the existing `sportanalitica-3tdk8qV0` virtual environment, and then you can just reuse it ever time.

> if I install anything it says Pipfile.lock (295b1e) out of date, updating to (74c969)…

This is also part of pipenv's basic features. When you change something in your virtual environment (i.e. install a new package, uninstall a package, update a version), it will "compute" a new Pipfile.lock file to track the updates:

> ### $ pipenv lock
>
> `$ pipenv lock` is used to create a `Pipfile.lock`, which declares **all** dependencies (and sub-dependencies) of your project, their latest available versions, and the current hashes for the downloaded files. This ensures repeatable, and most importantly *deterministic*, builds.

The locking is automatically done when you `pipenv install`/`pipenv uninstall`. Locking is also part of pipenv's [security features](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#pipfile-lock-security-features).

Basically, what you just did (`pipenv shell` + `pipenv install`) follows the [Example Pipenv Workflow](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#example-pipenv-workflow) for pipenv. I recommend going through the [Basic Usage of Pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#basic-usage-of-pipenv) docs.